# Node.Js socket hang up when passing custom Error class into Express error middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write integration tests for my error handling middleware in my Node + Express server, and am experiencing a socket hang up when I pass in a custom error that extends Node's base error class.

**Err.ts**

```
class Err extends Error {
  public status: number;

  constructor(message: string, status: number) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

**errorHandler.ts**

```
const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err: Err, _req, res, _next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    success: false,
    error: err.message || 'Server error'
  });
};
```

**integration tests**

```
// SETUP

use(chaiHttp);

const app = express();

app.get('/foo', (_req, _res, next) => {
  return next(new Error());
});

app.get('/qux', (_req, _res, next) => {
  return next(new Err('foobar', 123));
});

app.use(errorHandler);

// TESTING GENERIC, NORMAL NODE ERROR --> THIS WORKS
it('returns a default error when error object is malformed', async () => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/foo');
  expect(res.status).to.equal(500);
  expect(res.body.error).to.equal('Server error');
});

// TESTING CUSTOM ERROR --> THIS THROWS THE SOCKET ERROR
it('returns the passed-in error as is', async () => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/qux');
  expect(res.status).to.equal(123);
  expect(res.body.error).to.equal('foobar');
});

// STACK
     Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
      at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:440:23)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

Something else worth noting is that when I `console.log(err.status, err.message)` in `errorHandler.ts`, I'm seeing `123` and `foobar` show up, so it's being passed into the middleware. But something seems to be happening at a lower level that I'm not privy to.

I've done some research and something seems to be happening where the process is closing improperly, but I'm not sure how extending the base error class would cause that to happen.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In my test, I was passing `123` as a foobar status code, which was then being passed in to `res.status(123)` in my error handler. I guess Node (or Express) has protections against sending invalid status codes, because once I changed the 123 to 400, the socket error went away.